# Send WhatsApp/Hangout (Gmail) message on background

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm wondering if it's possible to send a `WhatsApp message` or `Gmail message` on background, since now I'm doing a `Share to` :

```
public void WhatsAppMessage(View view) {
    Intent SendMessage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    SendMessage.setType("text/plain");
    String text = "MESSAGE GOES HERE";
    SendMessage.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (SendMessage != null) {
        SendMessage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(SendMessage, text));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to select a contact that you want to send the message, and then send it to him/her **without** open the APP itself?

Comment: Not using `startActivity()`. AFAIK, WhatsApp does not have an API, though you can always use a search engine to double-check that.

Comment: "you can always use a search engine to double-check that" what does it mean?

Comment: Search Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo, or your favorite search engine for something like `whatsapp android api`.

Comment: @CommonsWare What about `Gmail Hangouts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a good answer and finally I ended up using [JAVA mail API](https://nishitshah85.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/sending-mail-programatically-using-java-mail-api/) it lets to me to me send messages programmatically, since there is no API on `WhatsApp` or `Hangouts` it's not possible to do that.